# How to change background color of a button on click using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have 4 buttons. If I click on one of them, that button's background color should to blue. If that button is not clicked I want the color to remain the same (that color is red) . How do I do it?

Currently it only works for one button. Whenever I click another button, it changes the color of that button, not the one I clicked.

EDIT 1:
Here is my updated code.

```js
    function buttonFunction() {
    var buttons = new Array("button", "button1", "button2", "button3", "button4");
for (var i in buttons) {    
        if (onclick = true) {
            document.getElementById(buttons[i]).style.backgroundColor = "blue";
        }
    }
}

<body id="Body">
    <!-- Navigation bar setup -->
    <header id="Mainheader">
        <nav id="Navigation">
            <form>
                <button type="button" value="submit" class="Button" onclick="buttonFunction()" id="button"><a href="index.html" class="Button-link" >Introduction</a></button>
                <button type="button" value="submit" class="Button" onclick="buttonFunction()" id="button"><a href="History-of-astronomy.html" class="Button-link">History of Astronomy</a></button>
                <button type="button" value="submit" class="Button" onclick="buttonFunction()" id="button"><a href="Observational-Astronomy.html" class="Button-link" >Observational Astronomy</a></button>
                <button type="button" value="submit" class="Button" onclick="buttonFunction()" id="button"><a href="" class="Button-link">More on Astronomy</a></button>
            </form>
        </nav>
    </header>       
    <!-- Navigation bar setup (complete) -->
```

Comment: 1) Please only show *relevant code*. 2) What does that `for` with empty parentheses do? 3) `==` for *comparison* `=` for *assignment*...

Comment: oops.nothing. need to delete that.

Comment: anyways I need to go to sleep now (it is 11:30 pm). Talk tomorrow.

Comment: An id should be unique within the page. DO NOT use the same id for multiple elements.

Comment: I'm voting to close as unclear because in comments you've acknowledged that you need to delete the part of the code that Andrew mentioned yet you've then said you're going to go sleep now apparently without fixing that - that is, you've deliberately chosen to leave errors in your question. Plus there seems to be a bunch of irrelevant code shown. We're happy to help you in a general sense, but you shouldn't make us wade through misleading or irrelevant details to figure out what you're doing.

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/video-screencasts/150-hey-designers-know-one-thing-javascript-recommend/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the button reference in onclick function and change style of it.

```js
function buttonFunction(el) {
  el.style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
```

```html
<button type="button" value="submit" class="Button" onclick="buttonFunction(this)"><a href="index.html" class="Button-link">Introduction</a>
</button>
<button type="button" value="submit" class="Button" onclick="buttonFunction(this)"><a href="History-of-astronomy.html" class="Button-link">History of Astronomy</a>
</button>
<button type="button" value="submit" class="Button" onclick="buttonFunction(this)"><a href="Observational-Astronomy.html" class="Button-link">Observational Astronomy</a>
</button>
<button type="button" value="submit" class="Button" onclick="buttonFunction(this)"><a href="" class="Button-link">More on Astronomy</a>
</button>
```

Comment: Thanks, it working now. I also accepted your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Update the click handler function:

```
function buttonFunction(btn) {
    btn.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
}
```

And change the button declaration to:

```
<button type="button" value="submit" class="Button" onclick="buttonFunction(this)" id="button"><a href="" class="Button-link">More on Astronomy</a></button>
```